# Flextable package: how to remove a dot between two words in column names?

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to create a dataframe in R Studio where I can break down the columns into multiple sub-columns, which I have been able to do with a simplification of the code shown above. However, in the first few columns "Piste-Cyclable" and "Bande-Cyclable", it adds a dot between "Piste" and "Cyclable" whereas I would like just a space so that it looks nicer. I would also like the column to be perfectly centered between its three sub-columns, which I haven't been able to do either.

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
library(officer)



CYCLABLE_TOTAL_Piste <- 50
CYCLABLE_DGEEP_Piste <- 200
CYCLABLE_DACV_courante_Piste <- 150
CYCLABLE_A_TOTAL_Piste <- "150"
CYCLABLE_DGEEP_courante_Piste <- 250
CYCLABLE_DACV_courante_Piste <- 200

CYCLABLE_A_1_TOTAL_Piste <- 180
CYCLABLE_DGEEP_prec_Piste <- 300
CYCLABLE_DACV_prec_Piste <- 250

CYCLABLE_TOTAL_Piste <- 2


#FAKE DF
df <- data.frame(
Echelle = c("AL", 
          "BL", 
          "BL2"),
"Piste-Cyclable_Totaux"= c(CYCLABLE_TOTAL_Piste,
                         CYCLABLE_DGEEP_Piste,
                         CYCLABLE_DACV_courante_Piste),

"Piste-Cyclable_2023"  = 
c(as.character(CYCLABLE_A_TOTAL_Piste), 
                         CYCLABLE_DGEEP_courante_Piste,
                         CYCLABLE_DACV_courante_Piste),

"Piste-Cyclable_2022"  = c(CYCLABLE_A_1_TOTAL_Piste,
                         CYCLABLE_DGEEP_prec_Piste,
                         CYCLABLE_DACV_prec_Piste)
 )

 #Affiche le data frame 
 print(df)


 #Mise en forme du tableau
 df <- df |> 
 flextable() |> 
 separate_header(split = "_") |>  
 set_header_labels(Piste.Cyclable ="Piste Cyclable", 
 Bande.Cyclable = "Bande Cyclable") |>
 align(align = "center", part = "all", j = 1:4) |> 
 merge_v(j = 1) |> 
 valign(j = 1, valign = "top") |> 
 colformat_double(digits = 2) |> 
 align(align = "left", part = "all") |> 
 bg(bg = "#D3D3D3", part = "header") |> 
 bold(part = "header") |> 
 align(align = "left", part = "header") |> 
 autofit()

 df
```

I am encountering problems with the flextable package when trying to change the column names. It seems that the `set_header_labels` function should be used to change the column names, but it's not working for me. Additionally, I am not sure why the columns aren't centered.

I didn't see any example with a separate_header function before a set_header_labels

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example so that we can try to help? CYCLABLE_DGEEP_Piste is needed (I stop checking at this point, maybe there are other issues).

Comment: sorry, i thought it was a reproducible example, i added CYCLABLE_DGEEP

Comment: I am sorry, CYCLABLE_TOTAL_Piste and CYCLABLE_DGEEP_Piste are missing. Hope someone will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `labelizor()` and a function that replaces `.` by   for this case. In the following example, it operates on the whole *header* part.

```
ft <- df |> 
  flextable() |> 
  separate_header(split = "_") |>  
  set_header_labels(Piste.Cyclable ="Piste Cyclable", 
                    Bande.Cyclable = "Bande Cyclable") |>
  align(align = "center", part = "all", j = 1:4) |> 
  merge_v(j = 1) |> 
  valign(j = 1, valign = "top") |> 
  colformat_double(digits = 2) |> 
  align(align = "left", part = "all") |> 
  bg(bg = "#D3D3D3", part = "header") |> 
  bold(part = "header") |> 
  align(align = "left", part = "header") |> 
  labelizor(part = "header", labels = function(x) {
    gsub("\\.", " ", x)
  }) |> 
  autofit()

ft
```

[image]